# Trouble finding the pdf of a transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am doing this problem and I am having some trouble with it. The problem is as follows:

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the joint pdf of $f_{X1,X2}(x_1,x_2)= \exp(-x_1-x_2)$ with $x_1,x_2 >0$. For $w_1,w_2>0$ let $W = w_1X_1 + w_2X_2$ and find the pdf of W

My initial thought was to do a normal transformation to $W$ and get the pdf that way. But looking through my notes typically when we have a transformation variable like this one we usually take another variable say $Q$ and let it be $Q=X_2$ so that way we have a one-one transformation. But the problem with this is that it is asking for a pdf in just $W$ so would I still have to do the way I was thinking and then take the marginal pdf for $W$ ? Or is there something more that I am missing out. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: "The way (you were) thinking" might well be the most direct and the less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You have $W=w_1X_1+ w_2X_2$.

If you had $Q=X_2$ could you find $f_{W,Q}(w,q)$?

> $$f_{W,Q}(w,q) = \begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (q,(w-w_2q)/w_1)}{\partial (q,w)}\end{Vmatrix}~f_{X_1,X_2}((w-w_2q)/w_1,q) \\ = \dfrac 1{w_1}~\exp\left(\frac{(w_2-w_1)q-w)}{w_1}\right)\cdot\mathbf 1_{0<w_2q<w}$$

Well, $f_W(w) = \int_\Bbb R f_{W,Q}(w,q)\mathrm d q$

Comment: This is what the OP describes in their question -- so why the parroting?

Answer (score 0):

For $t > 0$, you have:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(W<t)=\int_{0}^{\frac{t}{w_{1}}} \left ( \int_{0}^{\frac{t-w_{1}x_{1}}{w_{2}}}e^{-x_{1}-x_{2}}dx_{2}\right) dx_{1}
\end{equation}
Evaluate. Then differentiate w.r.t. $t$ to get a closed expression for the pdf.